# Problem with manual code migration from C# to C

Tags: c#, c

I am trying to migrate a code written in C# to C for better performance and to be able to use it in another software as it supports C based DLL.

I have this function in C# which performs as expected

```
 private byte[] authDataExtract(byte[] concatenatedData)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] authData = null;
            authData = new byte[concatenatedData.Length - 10];
            int blockCount = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                if (concatenatedData.Length - 10 - blockCount < 4)
                    break;
                else if (concatenatedData.Length - 10 - blockCount >= 4)
                {
                    if ((isAllZero(concatenatedData, blockCount) == true) || (isAllff(concatenatedData, blockCount) == true)) //Modified to handle 0xFF padding - Sudhanwa 
                        break;
                    int dlc = int.Parse(concatenatedData[blockCount + 3].ToString("X2"), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);  //Modified to handle exceptiion in case of Padding CR - Sudhanwa 
                    //int dlc = int.Parse(bytetostring(concatenatedData[blockCount + 3]));



                    if ((dlc > concatenatedData.Length - 10 - blockCount))
                    {
                        authData = new byte[concatenatedData.Length - 10];
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(concatenatedData, 0, authData, 0, concatenatedData.Length - 10);
                        blockCount = concatenatedData.Length - 10;
                        break;
                    }
                    authData = new byte[blockCount + 4 + dlc];
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(concatenatedData, 0, authData, 0, blockCount + 4 + dlc);


                    blockCount += dlc + 4; 


            }
        }
        return authData;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }

}
```

I want to write  equivalent C code for this 
My current C code is

```
void authDataExtract(unsigned char payload [],unsigned int size_payload,unsigned char * arr)
{
//unsigned char rec_tMAC [8];
int blockcount=0;
int dlc=0;
//unsigned char* arr= NULL;
//memcpy(&rec_tMAC[0],&payload[size_payload-8],8);
//printArr(rec_tMAC,8);


  while (1)
  {
      if (size_payload- 10 - blockcount < 4)
          break;
       else if (size_payload - 10 - blockcount >= 4)
       {
            if ((isAllZero(payload,size_payload,blockcount) == true) || 
     (isAllff(payload,size_payload, blockcount) == true)) 
                    break;
                dlc= payload[blockcount + 3];

                 if ((dlc > size_payload - 10 - blockcount))
                    {
                        arr = (unsigned char*)calloc(size_payload-10,sizeof(unsigned char));
                        memcpy(arr,payload,size_payload-10);
                        blockcount = size_payload - 10;
                        break;
                    }

                   arr = (unsigned char*)calloc(blockcount + 4 + dlc,sizeof(unsigned char));

                   memcpy(arr,payload,blockcount + 4 + dlc);

                   blockcount += dlc + 4; 


       }

  }     
 }
```

> But it is giving exceptions with pointer .I believe I have an issue
>   with dynamic memory allocation.

Assuming the logic inc C# code is correct ,request your help to have exact same logic with C function.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: It is function that extracts specific bytes from byte array. For example consider byte array : 01 02 03,02,0E,0F,00,00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08 .Here I have to drop last 10 bytes.Then starting from left I have to skip first 3 bytes than read 4th byte which is 02 ,which means next 2 bytes of data is expected.So at the end of this ,I should get an array 01 02 03 02 0E 0F.[00 00 is padding which shall be dropped]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you see that `C#` function is returning `byte[]`

```
 private byte[] authDataExtract(byte[] concatenatedData)
```

But `C` function is not.

```
void authDataExtract(unsigned char payload [],unsigned int size_payload,unsigned char * arr)
```

> Note that `arr` is new variable and it is local to `authDataExtract`
>   function. It has no effect on the caller function.

---

Try as below.

```
unsigned  char* authDataExtract(unsigned char payload [],unsigned int size_payload,unsigned char * arr) {

   while(1) {
     ...
   }
   return arr; 
}
```

from `main`

```
  unsigned char *p  = authDataExtract(….);
  if (!p) error;
```

You could also use `pointer to pointer` but I leave that to you.

Comment: I made changes and it works now .I dint know how to properly return byte array in C.Instead of char* ,i returned unsigned char * . Thanks for prompt response.